# To climb (in) the rankings?

Tags: prepositions

When competing in a contest, is your goal:

> To climb the rankings

or

> To climb *in* the rankings

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the two sentence are completely appropriate. See, these are some headlines from news websites:

1. *climb the rankings*

   - Scotland climb world rankings
   - Congo Republic set to climb African oil producer rankings
   - Penn GSE Continues to Climb National Rankings
2. *climb in ranking(s)*

   - Blake Barnett Continues Climb In National Rankings
   - Swedish brands climb in global ranking
3. *climb up rankings*

   - Brazil continue slow climb up FIFA rankings
   - Kentucky's climb up recruiting rankings earns Mark Stoops a raise

Comment: These all seem reasonable examples. But beware of extracting or supporting rules from headlines; they have a tendency to bend the usual rules a lot, in ways that people tend not to in normal speech.

Answer (score 1):

I think that *the rankings* can be considered as a subject, like *a mountain* in the sentence *I climb a mountain*. However, when you add *to [something]*, you need to add *in* (ex: *The song climbed to number 5 in the ranking*).

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest either *climb the rankings* or *rise in the rankings*. The former has a more active connotation, suggesting that the subject is ascending due mostly to its own victories and successes. *Rise in the rankings* might be more appropriate in cases in which the subject's ascension is due at least in part to other competitors losing.

Answer (score -6):

The goal is to not merely climb the rankings, not merely ascend the rankings, but to surmount the rankings, to plant one's flag atop the striving heap, to look down on the pretenders, and inhale deeply the rarefied air of victory.

Comment: Are the downvotes the reason for wanting to leave? I know anonymous downvotes are frustrating, but why not visit [meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/) and ask there for some clarification?

Comment: Why did you receive the downvotes? Perhaps if you had placed the article in bold, people wouldn't have been so dumb, nevertheless an explanation would have been more helpful.

Comment: I can see this answer is garnering downvotes: this means that (currently) five people think it "not useful". I haven't downvoted, but perhaps they think that because they feel it's not very easy to see how this answers the OP's question about whether the preposition *in* is necessary or desirable. At least, that's what the question appears to be asking; perhaps that could have been more explicit.

Comment: I apologize for the increasing number of downvotes this answer receives, it is a backlash caused by my criticism of the community's uncooperativeness. My purpose was to to drum up support in favour of downvoters who leave comments, instead this is the result, three downvotes since my notification.